# How to increase fontsize and adjust the string in multiple rows in cell in kableExtra table?

Tags: r, r-markdown, pdflatex

I want to increase font-size in table by using kable-Extra package in r-markdown pdf.
Tried using kable_styling but after increasing to 50 there is no change.if particular string length is more it should automatically adjust to new line. and i also want the row height should be of same length. for all tables.  below is my code

```
  ---
title: "Untitled"
output:
  pdf_document: 
    keep_tex: true
classoption: svgnames
header-includes:
- \pagenumbering{gobble}
- \usepackage{fancyhdr}
- \usepackage{lipsum}
- \pagestyle{fancy}
- \fancyhead{}
- \fancyfoot{} 
- \lfoot[LE,LO]{This is my footer}
- \fancypagestyle{plain}{\pagestyle{fancy}}
- \usepackage{booktabs}
- \usepackage{longtable}
---
kbl(df,booktabs = T)%>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped","hold_position","repeat_header"),bootstrap_options = "bordered",font_size = 7)%>%
  column_spec(1, width = "8cm")%>%
  row_spec(0, bold = T, color = "white", background = "#008000")%>%
  # pack_rows("A", 1, 2)%>%
  pack_rows("B", 1, 2)%>%
  pack_rows("C", 3, 8)%>%
  pack_rows("D", 9, 10)%>%
  pack_rows("E", 11, 13)%>%
  pack_rows("F", 14, 15)%>%
  pack_rows("G", 16, 19)%>%
  pack_rows("H", 20, 22)%>%
  pack_rows("I", 23, 25)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, @D A! Actually, when using `"scale_down"`, the `font_size` argument is no longer valid.

Comment: @bttomio Thank You.! , if i remove scaledown the table is overlaying on footer.

Comment: @bttomio i have edited full code can you please take a look why table is overlaying on footer do i need to change any settings here

Comment: You're welcome. Where does the footer come from (it's not in the `kbl` function)? Could you please edit your question to include the part of the footer? Anyway, I cannot replicate your table because `df` is not provided.

Comment: @bttomio yes, i have edited. it's ***page footer*** appears in every page  i have used using latex packages.

Comment: I see, thanks. If the table is overlapping, it needs to be reduced. You need to change the `font_size`. Another solution would be to set `landscape()`, more information [here](https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf). By the way, an image of the problem could help in finding a solution.

Comment: landscape() doesn't work for me. what ever the table i want it to continue in next page without overlap. actually i'm new to rmarkdown so i'm working with the same pdf which you have shared :) . it mentions only about that package not entirely regarding rmarkdown

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/latex-header.html.